# Proper way to handle many event listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

In my website, I have a dynamically growing list, (from a database) that has buttons attached to each item of the list. The button goes to the same javascript function, but each element in the list has a different id, which needs to be included inside the function when it is running.

I'm currently using `onclick` in the html and can pass the id through the function's parameter, as I am using template literals to render the list.

Is there any way that I can do this with event listeners?

An example of what I currently have would be:

```
onclick="theFunction('id')"
```

which changes for every item in the list, so the list could look like

```html
<ul>
<li onclick="theFunction('id1')">name1</li>
<li onclick="theFunction('id2')">name2</li>
<li onclick="theFunction('id3')">name3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Inside the event listener, `this` is the element that you clicked on, you can use `this.id` to get its ID.

Comment: @Barmar If I had many of these lists, each one going to a different function, what would be the best approach?

Comment: I thought you said the elements have IDs. Shouldn't it be `<li id="id1" onclick=...>`?

Comment: Or is `id1` the ID of some other element that clicking on this button should do something with?

Comment: @CertainPerformance no, it doesn't. I'll edit the question. Sorry.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry for not making myself clear - my bad - your correct in your latest comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation instead: attach *one* listener to the `<ul>`, and then on click, check to see if the clicked element was a `<li>`. If so, check an attribute of the `<li>` to figure out what parameter to call `theFunction` with. For example:

```js
const theFunction = console.log;

document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('li')) {
    return;
  }
  const param = 'id' + e.target.dataset.param;
  theFunction(param);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-param="1">name1</li>
  <li data-param="2">name2</li>
  <li data-param="3">name3</li>
</ul>
```

Note how the `onclick` attributes have been replaced with `data-param` attributes.